# multiple screens to scroll horizontally, but not vertically

Tags: android, android-viewpager, horizontal-scrolling, baseadapter

I am trying to achieve multiple scrollable views on one activity.
I am using viewpager, in each screen there will be multiple buttons using baseadapter, where clicking on one will start certain level, similar to what you see in many of the current games.
I managed to do this and it is all good, one thing I couldn't do is to stop the page/buttons from scrolling vertically, even when all buttons are already on display, you still can scroll them up and down :(

when you scroll horizontally, it goes to the next/previous page, that is good, but how to disable scrolling vertically?

I am considering doing the hole thing in canvas, and make it from scratch, I just don't want to do it the hard way and want to learn the easy way of doing it, if there is any.